# solve a second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can we solve analytically (find a closed form solution) the second order ODE

$$x^{\alpha}y^{\prime\prime}=y,\quad x>0$$
where $\alpha\in\,]0,1[$.
Consider the conditions
$$y(0)=1,\quad y^{\prime}(0)=1$$
 This equation appears in a fractional model that describes viscoelasticity properties in certain materials.

Comment: Fourier transform?

Comment: Could you precise the boundary conditions ?

Comment: @ Rushabh Mehta. Fourier transform is not easy due to the fractional exponent.

Comment: Claude Leibovici. I added the initial conditions, though not sure how that helps find a general solution.

Comment: @ Mattos. That at best would give a special function. Can we go around that?

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by 'go around that'. If the series solution is a special function, then the solution to the problem is a special function.

Comment: @ Mattos. Of course. I mean is there any thing else we can try with before looking at series solutions.

Comment: Mathematica gives an answer in terms of the modifies Bessel function of the first kind.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica gives the answer in terms of the modified Bessel function of the first kind $I_{n}$
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

[image]

Actually this is the solution of $$x^{1-\alpha}y^{\prime\prime}=y$$

Comment: This does not seem to take into account the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Can you get the solution for a general $\alpha$ ?

Comment: What I would like is to see how you could simplify the expression you give taking into account $x >0$. This would make the argument of Bessel functions to be $\frac{2x^{\frac{a+1}2}}{a+1}$ and a leading factor $\sqrt x$. Similarly, make a full simplfication of the front coefficients. Finally, apply the boundary conditions; this should again give something much better. Please, add the results of all of that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment.*

As you wrote in you answer,  it seems that you obtained solutions in terms of Bessel $I$ functions (the expressions you gave could be simplified quite a lot). As I wrote in comments, I suppose that they would become even simpler when using the given boundary conditions.

Playing with the case where $\alpha=\frac mn$ ($m$ and $n$ being integers) and using the boundary conditions, it seems that they also can express in terms of hypergeometric functions where patterns seem to appear (I let you finding them). 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 m & n & y(x) \\
 1 & 2 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{1}{3};\frac{4
   x^{3/2}}{9}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{5}{3};\frac{4
   x^{3/2}}{9}\right)\\
 1 & 3 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{2}{5};\frac{9
   x^{5/3}}{25}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{8}{5};\frac{9
   x^{5/3}}{25}\right)\\
 1 & 4 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{3}{7};\frac{16
   x^{7/4}}{49}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{11}{7};\frac{16
   x^{7/4}}{49}\right)\\
 1 & 5 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{4}{9};\frac{25
   x^{9/5}}{81}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{14}{9};\frac{25
   x^{9/5}}{81}\right)\\
 1 & 6 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{5}{11};\frac{36
   x^{11/6}}{121}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{17}{11};\frac{36
   x^{11/6}}{121}\right)\\
 1 & 7 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{6}{13};\frac{49
   x^{13/7}}{169}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{20}{13};\frac{49
   x^{13/7}}{169}\right) \\
 2 & 3 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{1}{4};\frac{9
   x^{4/3}}{16}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{7}{4};\frac{9
   x^{4/3}}{16}\right)\\
 2 & 5 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{3}{8};\frac{25
   x^{8/5}}{64}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{13}{8};\frac{25
   x^{8/5}}{64}\right)\\
 2 & 7 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{5}{12};\frac{49
   x^{12/7}}{144}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{19}{12};\frac{49
   x^{12/7}}{144}\right)\\
 3 & 4 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{1}{5};\frac{16
   x^{5/4}}{25}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{9}{5};\frac{16
   x^{5/4}}{25}\right)\\
 3 & 5 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{2}{7};\frac{25
   x^{7/5}}{49}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{12}{7};\frac{25
   x^{7/5}}{49}\right)\\
 3 & 7 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{4}{11};\frac{49
   x^{11/7}}{121}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{18}{11};\frac{49
   x^{11/7}}{121}\right)\\
 3 & 8 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{5}{13};\frac{64
   x^{13/8}}{169}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{21}{13};\frac{64
   x^{13/8}}{169}\right)\\
 4 & 5 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{1}{6};\frac{25
   x^{6/5}}{36}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{11}{6};\frac{25
   x^{6/5}}{36}\right)\\
 4 & 7 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{3}{10};\frac{49
   x^{10/7}}{100}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{17}{10};\frac{49
   x^{10/7}}{100}\right)\\
 4 & 9 &  \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{5}{14};\frac{81
   x^{14/9}}{196}\right)+x \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{23}{14};\frac{81
   x^{14/9}}{196}\right)
\end{array}
\right) $$